# Count consecutive occurrences of a value in rows of R data frame

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns

I would like to do count the consecutive occurrences in rows of R data frame whenever the first column takes that value and save the results in a new variable. If this was my data and I was interested in values of one:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  C = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  D = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  E = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
)
```

I would want to create the following output:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  C = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  D = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  E = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  count = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 4)
)
```

I tried something like this but am not really certain if this is sensible:

```
df$count <- apply(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)], 1, function(x) {
  r <- rle(x == 1)
  max(r$lengths[r$values])
})
```

And it also does not yet take into account that I am interested in spells starting at the first column.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rle`

```
cbind(df, count = apply(df, 1, function(x) 
  ifelse(x[1] == 1, max(rle(x)$lengths), 0)))
  A B C D E count
1 1 0 1 0 1     1
2 0 0 1 1 0     0
3 1 1 0 0 1     2
4 0 1 1 0 0     0
5 1 1 1 1 0     4
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adapting your solution. Instead of `max(rle(x)$lengths)`, I specified `rle(x)$lengths[1]`, which would avoid problems if the first run of 1 wasn't the longest

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  C = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  D = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  E = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
)

df |> 
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(count = if_else(A ==1, 
                         sum(consecutive_id(c_across(everything())) == 1),
                         0))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A     B     C     D     E count
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     1     0     1     1
#> 2     0     0     1     1     0     0
#> 3     1     1     0     0     1     2
#> 4     0     1     1     0     0     0
#> 5     1     1     1     1     0     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternative solution using `match()` instead of `consecutive_id()`:

```r
df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(count = match(FALSE, c_across(everything()) == 1) - 1)
```

You can transpose the dataframe if you do not want to use `rowwise()`:

```r
df |> 
  t() |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  summarize(across(everything(), \(x) match(FALSE, x == 1) - 1)) |> 
  set_names(colnames(df))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>       A     B     C     D     E
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0     2     0     4
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great, but in the end was a bit too slow for the data I'm using

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Nothing seems to beat `apply()` in this case. If your main concern is speed, `which.min(x == 1) - 1` seems to perform a bit better than the solution with `rle()` in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

another way using runlength encoding (`rle`) and "tidy" notation:

```
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(first_runlength = unlist(rle(c_across(A:E)))[1],
         first_runlength = ifelse(A, first_runlength, 0)
         )
```